# Parse .ini file from resource during runtime using C++/boost

Tags: c++, winapi, embedded-resource, ini, boost-propertytree

I have an .ini file which is located inside the resource as an RCDATA.
I load it from the resource during runtime, and I am able to get it as a very long string.

I am interested of loading the .ini file (from the resource at runtime) and parse it as an .ini file using Boost or Win32 API but the question is how do I do it ?

It seems that it is possible of doing such thing using [QT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27585540/can-i-read-from-ini-file-which-located-in-resources-files).

I have tried loading the resource file and assigning `read_ini()` the binary data/string file but it doesn't iterate over it afterwards.

Is it possible of doing such thing ?

### Code snip:

```
HRSRC myResource = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(101), RT_RCDATA);
unsigned int myResourceSize = SizeofResource(NULL, myResource);
HGLOBAL myResourceData = LoadResource(NULL, myResource);
char* pMyBinaryData = (char*)LockResource(myResourceData);
char *text = (char*)malloc(myResourceSize + 1);
memcpy(text, pMyBinaryData, myResourceSize);
text[myResourceSize] = 0;//last char array is null
FreeResource(myResourceData);
```

The way I extract the text inside the .txt/.ini file.

Comment: Show us what the problem is ("binary data/string file but it doesn't iterate over it afterwards" doesn't tell us anything unless we see what you did in code)

Comment: Yes this is possible.

Comment: sehe, post edited.

@DavidHeffernan, Please provide an explanation/example. Thank you.

Comment: Example of what? You want us to write all this code for you?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You could choose 'explanation' and not 'example'. no one is asking for "ze c0des".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you *might* be looking for

```
std::istringstream iss(the_large_string_value);

boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
boost::property_tree::read_ini(iss, pt);
```

Of course, you can read (really large) resources as a stream. Boost IOstreams has an `array_source` that can help there.

The simplest thing here would be

```
std::string the_large_resource_string_value(pMyBinaryData, myResourceSize);
```